# Java tryLock release lock on multiple JVM

Tags: java, nio, filelock

I have problem with file lock on Linux in Java
I have two apps on different hosts(A and B) and shared folder for file lock.
In A I get lock with `channel.lock()`.
Then I call `channel.tryLock()` in B. It throws `OverlappingFileLockException`. And its ok.
But then I call `channel.tryLock()` in A (It throws `OverlappingFileLockException`). After this, in B `channel.tryLock()` returns valid lock without any exceptions.

Did someone had same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the Java Doc (method `tryLock()`)

> If it fails to acquire a lock because an overlapping lock is held by
>   another program then it returns null. **If it fails to acquire a lock
>   for any other reason then an appropriate exception is thrown.**

This means the `tryLock` method will throw an `OverlappingFileLockException`, if there is an other problem than an other application having the lock.

If you are multi-threaded, you should know this:

> File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. *They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine.*

If you keep reading about that exception:

> OverlappingFileLockException - If a lock that overlaps the requested
>   region is already held by this Java virtual machine, or if another
>   thread is already blocked in this method and is attempting to lock an
>   overlapping region of the same file

So I think your problem is that you are trying to acquire a lock from withhin the same application that already has one. You would have to check it for me, but it seems like in this case it will not return `null`, but throw an Exception.

Also: The Documentation does not say anything about what happens if you try to lock the file from the same application. It always speaks about returning `null`, if an other application has acquired the lock:

> A lock object representing the newly-acquired lock, **or null if the
>   lock could not be acquired because *another program* holds an
>   overlapping lock**

[Link to JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28long,%20long,%20boolean%29)

Comment: I don't know what the reason for this behavior approach is, but if it is like I said, it might be a bit of a design flaw.

Comment: Not really; file locks are a relatively low-level consstruct provided by the OS to facilitate cross-process synchronization, not intra-process synchronization.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos That makes sense, I don't remember how that goes exactly. Thanks for the clarification. Can you confirm this is because of the intra-process synchronization?

Comment: I think your answer is correct; I just wanted to clarify why this behavior exists. At least in Linux, for performance reasons by default all threads share the same file descriptor tables, thus another thread is not another program...